# Activesync: Sendmail command with MIME Type

Tags: ios, encoding, mime-types, sendmail, activesync

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <SendMail xmlns="ComposeMail:" xmlns:airsync="AirSync">
     <ClientId>34234243</ClientId>
     <SaveInSentItems />
     <Mime>
        From:xxx@.com 
        To:yyy@.com 
        Subject:342234 MIME-Version: 1.0 
        Content-Type: text/plain; 
        charset="iso-8859-1" 
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
         X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2900.3350 234234
        This is body  
     </Mime>
     </SendMail>
```

I am working with SendEmail command. I am looking for way to send Mime content to server. I have tried:

- Convert the above xml in wbxml and setBOdy HTTP request but server return 103 error code.
- Convert the Content betweent  to Base64, and append to old string like this:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SendMail xmlns="ComposeMail:" xmlns:airsync="AirSync"><ClientId>34234243</ClientId>
  <SaveInSentItems/>
  <Mime>
   text encode base 64
  </Mime>
  </SendMail>
  ```

And convert to wbxml, send to server and receive error code 119 mean :MessageHasNoRecipient
The message being sent contains no recipient.
Anybody help? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get clientID?

Comment: It is random number i created, server will not validate the field.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am implementing the same thing but getting error code 400 not sure what is issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you have a blank character before the "To" keyword in your code.
Let's remove it. Your data before you encode it to base64 encoding must to look like this:

```
   From: xxx@xxx.com
   To: xxx@xxx.com 
   Subject: Mail Subject 
   MIME-Version: 1.0 
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 

   Test body
```

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my whole day!

Answer (score 0):

From MS documentation Mime element must be opaque BLOB https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg663453(v=exchg.80).aspx.
So you must write Mime data as CDATA.

```
<Mime>
<![CDATA[From: xxx@xxx.com
To: xxx@xxx.com 
Subject: Mail Subject 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 

Test body]]>
</Mime>
```